# Why does a particular solution to a mixing tank not exist?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I'm trying to model the following:

> Assume that paraffin and diesel are mixed together in a tank with a
>   capacity of 1000 litres. Pure diesel is pumped into the tank at a rate
>   of 20 litres per day **while pure paraffin is pumped into the tank at
>   the rate of 60 litres  per day**. The mixture in the tank is always kept
>   well mixed together, and is pumped out at a rate of 80 litres per day.
>   Let X denote the amount of diesel in the tank on day t measured in
>   litres.

I did not consider the part in  bold when modelling the equation because  the volume coming in is equal to volume coming out. My differential equation modelling the above is:

$\frac{dx}{dt} = 20 - \frac{80x}{1000} $

$\frac{dx}{dt} = 20 - {0.08x} $

Now suppose I want to solve for a particular solution such that:

> If x(0) = 500, solve the differential equation for X.

**My general solution is:**

$\int{\frac{1}{20-0.08x}dx} = \int t $

${\frac{-1}{0.08}ln|20-0.08x|} = t + c$

${e^{ln|20-0.08x|}} = e^{-0.08(t + c)}$

$20-0.08x = e^{-0.08(t + c)}$

**My attempt of particular solution is:**

$20-0.08(500) = e^{-0.08((0) + c)}$

$-20 = e^{-0.08c}$

At this point in time there is no value of c such that this equation is valid (because we cannot take a ln of a negative number) and therefore there is no particular solution. Where did I go wrong? What is even more absurd is that if I remodel the equations so that X is the paraffin and not the diesel (which is another way to model it), I get a particular solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a bit new here, so I might not be able to depict everything properly as I am not familiar with MathJax.

The problem is when you're integrating 1/x, you're simply putting it as ln(x) whereas it should be ln|x|. If you correct that you'll be able to get a particular solution for your equation. You can read more about it here

[What is the integral of 1/x?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206032/what-is-the-integral-of-1-x)