# Is is possible to evaluate $\int \frac{1-\text{sech}(\pi x)}{x} \, dx$ to some reasonable form?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, hyperbolic-functions

Is it possible to evaluate this integral to some reasonable formula?
$$\int \frac{1-\text{sech}(\pi  x)}{x} \, dx$$

I used integration by parts and got this result:

$$\int \frac{1-\text{sech}(\pi  x)}{x} \, dx=-\frac{2}{\pi} \int \frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\tanh \left(\frac{\pi  x}{2}\right)\right)}{x^2} \, dx+\log (x)-\frac{2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\tanh \left(\frac{\pi  x}{2}\right)\right)}{\pi  x}$$

Hoping for simplifying somehow $\tan ^{-1}\left(\tanh \left(\frac{\pi  x}{2}\right)\right)$ but without any success.

Comment: As Einstein could have said, the cocept of *some reasonable formula* is very relative. Nice problem. Cheers :-)

Comment: Seriously updated !

Comment: @TymaGaidash. I changed a lot of things using the hypergeometric function and deriving the reccurences. I think it is cleaner now. What do you think about my anwer ? Your is nice.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I have posted a bit of feedback in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exact formula with (if I am not mistaken) globally convergent series:

$$\frac{1-\text{sech}(\pi  x)}{x}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{4}{\pi  x} \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n (2 n+1)}{(2 n+1)^2+4 x^2}$$

So we have:

$$\int \frac{1-\text{sech}(\pi  x)}{x} \, dx=\frac{2}{\pi } \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n (2 n+1) \log \left((2 n+1)^2+4 x^2\right)}{(2 n+1)^2}$$

If someone is interested how I found these results - I used some of formulas from this [wolfram site page](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Sech/introductions/Sech/05/ShowAll.html) and from [Partial fraction expansion section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Partial_fraction_expansion) of Wikipedia page on Trigonometric functions.

Comment: Lots and lots of manipulation, I have no time to write it all here. I am trying to derive another variant of formula now.

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash: Even simpler formula added...

Comment: What is the inspiration for the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

One method is to use the series expansion for $\text{sech}(x)$ in the form
$$ \text{sech}(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{E_{2n} \, x^{2n}}{(2n)!} \hspace{10mm} |x| < \frac{\pi}{2}.$$
This leads to
\begin{align}
I &= \int \frac{1 - \text{sech}(\pi x)}{x} \, dx \\
&= - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{E_{2n} \, \pi^{2n}}{(2n)!} \, \int x^{2n-1} \, dx \\
&= - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{E_{2n} \, (\pi \, x)^{2n}}{(2n) \, (2n)!} + c_{0}
\end{align}
for $|x| < \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: How about for complex x or at least |x|$\ge\frac12$? Also is $E_y$ the yth Euler Number or something else?

Comment: Nice, although very limited convergence. I need it also for larger real `x`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with justified steps at the end:

$$\mathrm{\int\frac{1-sech(\pi x)}{x}dx=ln(x)-\int \frac{sech(\pi x)}{x}dx=ln(x)-2\int \frac{1}{1-\left(-e^{2\pi x}\right)}\frac{e^{\pi x}}{x}dx=ln(x)-2\int \frac{e^{\pi x}}{x} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-e^{2\pi x}\right)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\int\frac{e^{(2n+1)\pi x}}{x}dx= \boxed{\mathrm{ C+ln(x)-2\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n Ei((2 n+1) π x)}}, \left| -e^{2\pi x}\right|<1\implies \boxed{\mathrm{Re(x)<0}}}$$

1. Integrate the reciprocal function.
2. Use the [main definition of the hyperbolic secant function](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Sech/02/) and use partial fractions.
3. Use the [Best Friend Geometric Series expansion](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Ux7vl6zXxj0)
4. Rearrange and factor using algebra and integrating term by term.
5. Use the [definition of the Exponential Integral function](http://specialfunctionswiki.org/index.php/Exponential_integral_Ei)
6. Simplify and add constant of integration.
7. First please see [What is the integral of $\frac1x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206032/what-is-the-integral-of-1-x/206040). Note the ln(x) is not a typo. The absolute value bars would cause
   the complex numbers to be calculated wrongly. This means the negative signs must cancel for x$< 0$ in integration , for example:
   $\mathrm{a,b\ge0:ln(-b)-ln(-a)=ln\left(\frac
   {-b}{-a}\right)=ln(b)-ln(a)=ln|-b|-ln|-a|}$

For an example see this [computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln%28-1-3sqrt%28-1%29%29-ln%28-1%29+-2sum+%28%28-1%29%5En%28Ei%28%28-1-3sqrt%28-1%29%29%282n%2B1%29pi+%29-Ei%28-1%282n%2B1%29pi+%29%29%29+from+n%3D0+to+200) and this [other computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%281-sech%28pix%29%29%2Fx+from++-1+to+-1-3+sqrt%28-1%29+) for a sum representation of:

$$\mathrm{\int_{-1}^{-1-3i} \frac{1-sech(\pi x)}{x}dx= \frac{ln(5)+ln(2)}{2}+tan^{-1}(3)i-2i\pi -2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[(-1)^n\big(Ei((-1-3i)(2n+1)\pi )-Ei(-(2n+1)\pi )\big)\right]=1.12618…+1.25671…i}$$

Notice that the function is odd, so you do not necessarily need $\mathrm{Re(x)>0}$. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: The convergence here is for all $Re(x)<0$. This is also the simplest answer in terms of character usage.

Comment: $Ei(x)$ is exponential integral... so you just replaced one integral with sum of infinite integrals.

Comment: @azerbajdzan Yes it works. Please click the [Computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln%28-1-3sqrt%28-1%29%29-ln%28-1%29+-2sum+%28%28-1%29%5En%28Ei%28%28-1-3sqrt%28-1%29%29%282n%2B1%29pi+%29-Ei%28-1%282n%2B1%29pi+%29%29%29+from+n%3D0+to+200) [links](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%281-sech%28pix%29%29%2Fx+from++-1+to+-1-3+sqrt%28-1%29+). If Claude Leibovici used the hypergeometric function, then I do not see why I cannot use the [Ei function](http://specialfunctionswiki.org/index.php/Exponential_integral_Ei). I can write the Ei function as a sum if you want.

Comment: I am not saying that it does not work. Your formula works in its convergence range but I think that there might be formulas avoiding integrals and with much wider range of convergence.

Answer (score 2):

Using the sequence of substitutions
$$\pi x=y \qquad y=2 \tanh ^{-1}(z) \qquad z=\sqrt w\implies \color{blue} {x=\frac{2 }{\pi }\tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{w}\right)}$$

$$I= \int \frac{1 - \text{sech}(\pi x)}{x} \, dx= \int \frac{\sqrt{w}}{\left(1-w^2\right) \tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{w}\right)}\,dw$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{w}}{\tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{w}\right)}=1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \,w^n$$

Looking at sequence $A216272$ in $OEIS$
$$a_n=\frac 1 {2n-1}\sum _{m=0}^{2 n-1} \frac{2^{m+1} }{m+1} \binom{2 n-1}{m}\sum _{k=0}^{m+1} \frac{k!\,
   S_{k+m}^{(m)}\, \mathcal{S}_{m+1}^{(k)}}{(k+m)!}$$ where appear Stirling numbers of the first and second kinds.
The first coefficients $a_n$ are
$$\left\{\frac{1}{3},\frac{4}{45},\frac{44}{945},\frac{428}{14175},\frac{10196}{46777
   5},\frac{10719068}{638512875},\frac{25865068}{1915538625},\frac{5472607916}{4884
   62349375},\cdots\right\}$$
$$I=\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{1+w}{1-w}\right)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \int \frac {w^n}{1-w^2}\,dw$$ with
$$J_n=\int \frac {w^n}{1-w^2}\,dw=\frac{w^{n+1} }{n+1}\,\, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{n+1}{2};\frac{n+1}{2}+1;w^2\right)$$ and the reccurences are simply

$$J_{2n+1}=J_{2n-1}-\frac{w^{2n}}{2n}\qquad \text{with} \qquad J_1=-\frac{1}{2} \log \left(1-w^2\right)$$
$$J_{2n+2}=J_{2n}-\frac{w^{2n-1}}{2n-1}\qquad \text{with} \qquad J_0=\tanh ^{-1}(w)$$

Now, integrating from $w=0$ to   $w=\frac 9{10}$ that is to say from $x=0$ to $x=\frac{2 }{\pi }\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}\right)$, numerical integration gives as a result $1.09693$.

Computing
$$K_p=\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{1+w}{1-w}\right)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\, J_n$$ the results are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & K_p \\
 10 & 1.09969 \\
 20 & 1.09725 \\
 30 & 1.09698 \\
 40 & 1.09694 \\
 50 & 1.09693
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: I guess you forgot those `arctanh` and `arctan` functions in the last line. The convergence is only in `|z|<1`.

Comment: @Claude Just to verify, is the convergence only for |z|<1; it seems like the hypergeometric function should impact the rate? You should also post the entire answer without any substitutions. It is a resourceful answer.