# Isn't my book wrongly finding this anti derivative?

Tags: calculus, integration

**Question:**

Find the following integral: $\int{(1+x^{-1}+x^{-2})dx}$

**My book's attempt:**

$$\int{(1+x^{-1}+x^{-2})dx}$$

$$...$$

$$x+\ln x-x^{-1}\tag{1}$$

Shouldn't the answer be $x+\ln|x|-x^{-1}$ instead of $(1)$?

Comment: The answer should be $x + \ln |x| - x^{-1} + C$, where $C$ is a constant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the integral of 1/x?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206032/what-is-the-integral-of-1-x)

Comment: Yes the answer should be  $x + \ln |x| - x^{-1} + C$ with $C$ the constant of integration.

Comment: Yes. But is there other context in the problem that would let you assume $x>0$?

Comment: If we really want to describe all anti-derivatives on the largest possible domain, the most general answer is actually $$ \begin{cases} x + \ln(-x) - x^{-1} + C_1 & x<0 \\ x + \ln x - x^{-1} + C_2 & x>0 \end{cases} $$

Comment: @electronpusher no sir, no context is given that would let me assume that x>0.

Answer (score 2):

This is debatable.

If you want to apply the FTC, you will subtract two values of this antiderivative,

$$\int_a^b\frac{dx}{x}=\log b-\log a=\log\frac ba$$
or
$$\int_a^b\frac{dx}{x}=\log|b|-\log|a|=\log\left|\frac ba\right|.$$

But as the integrand has a singularity at $x=0$, $a,b$ may not differ in sign.

For this reason, I prefer the non-standard expression.

Also note that

$$\begin{cases}x<0\to\log(-x)+C_-,\\x>0\to\log(x)+C_+\end{cases}$$ is also a valid antiderivative.

Comment: But the first version doesn't easily describe $\int_{-2}^{-1} \frac{dx}{x}$, without the complication of a complex log branch.

Comment: @aschepler: there is no perfect solution.

Comment: @ryang: check the comments and most texbooks. :-)

Comment: Why would the comments and textbooks know what *you* are trying to say? I was merely suggesting a disambiguation edit.

Comment: @aschepler Untrue, since you can use the antiderivative family you yourself provided, which coincides with Bobby's, to apply the fundamental theorem of calculus: refer to the part where $x\lt0.$